# Using terraform in an AWS SSO+Okta environment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using SSO in an AWS SSO+Control Tower+Okta environment

When I login to AWS via Okta, I use the Option 1 setting to allow me to use the aws command

[Get credentials for AdministratorAccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJsdW.png)

When I run the terraform plan, I get the following error
There is no problem with terraform init.

【terraform plan error】

```
╷
│ Error: AccessDenied: Access Denied
│   status code: 403, request id: QN738HDZPQKMERFX, host id: roylHCGU3cOMfwkWjdpbeG991Ho28bredvY1/6vSgGavaM/VXn6rNtDSGIpnBS2cqetL38YdF1o=
│ 
│ 
╵
```

I thought the above error might be due to the fact that I cannot access the terraform.tfstate that I have set in backend.tf, but the following command completes successfully

【backend.tf】

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket               = "test-tfstate2"
    key                  = "provisioning/test/static/production/terraform.tfstate"
    region               = "ap-northeast-1"
    workspace_key_prefix = ""
  }
}
```

【command】
aws s3 ls s3://test-tfstate2/provisioning/test/static/production/terraform.tfstate

【Result】
2022-02-17 18:18:05          0 terraform.tfstate

What is the cause of the AccessDenied error in this situation?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your `provider` block look like?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
The provider block is as follows
`provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-northeast-1"
}`

Comment: So the provider version would probably be `4.x`?

Comment: Gentlemen. Thanks for the advice!
I ran the terraform plan in debug mode and found out that I am specifying a non-existent bucket in remote_state.tf After setting the correct bucket, both terraform plan/apply were successful! Your advice was very helpful!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you, Tetsuya! I would highly appreciate marking the answer with "DEBUG" suggestion as accepted one :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to troubleshoot this issue further and find the root cause of the problem you can execute:

```
TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform plan
```

This should give you exact reason while **plan** is failing. I suspect it's due to the permission issue: "Validate Response s3/ListObjects failed" but we need to confirm it first by running plan with the DEBUG option.

It could also happen that your terraform uses default credentials from **~/.aws/credentials** file. That's why when you execute `aws ls s3 ...` manually - it works, but it doesn't work with terraform.

To avoid this, please use option 2 from the guide you provided (by creating additional configuration block in your **~/.aws/credentials** file.

Then you can do `export AWS_PROFILE={name_of_your_new_profile}` and then try to execute **terraform plan** once again.

If all of this will not work, please update your question with the DEBUG's output.

Best of luck :)